# Drawing a circle at random coordinates

Tags: java

I have generated random x and y coordinates using the below method. Using the coordinates obtained from the method I need to draw a circle. I couldn't get the circle at the coordinates obtained from the code. Here is my code:

```
public String randomGen(int div1,int xMin1,int yMin1,int xMax1,int yMax)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int e;
    int i;
    int g = div1;
    Vector tem=new Vector();
    HashSet<Integer> xrandomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> yrandomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (i = 0; i < g; i++) 
    {
        e = rand.nextInt(xMax1-xMin1);
        System.out.println("e val -- "+e);
        if (xrandomNumbers.size() <= div1) 
        {
            if (xrandomNumbers.size() == div1) 
            {
                g = div1;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("X Random Numbers::"+xrandomNumbers);

        g = div1;
        for (i = 0; i < g; i++) 
        {
            e = rand.nextInt(yMax1-yMin1);
            if (yrandomNumbers.size() <= div1) 
            {
                if (yrandomNumbers.size() == div1) 
                {
                    g = div1;
                }
                g++;
                e=e+yMin1;
                yrandomNumbers.add(e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Y Random Numbers::"+yrandomNumbers);

        return xrandomNumbers+";"+yrandomNumbers;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you returning a String instead of a Point or an int array with the two variables packed in there? Are you splitting on ";" to get the two numbers that are returned from the method?

Comment: Yes am using the split function.

Comment: You haven't posted the circle drawing method.

Comment: Can you draw a circle at non-random coordinates? If not, fix that first. If you can, make sure your coordinates make sense. (And you're probably going to lose points for the string Martin pointed out.)

Comment: Thanks Martin Dinov & Keshlam..Solved the problem.